# zsh: command not found: dotnet-ef

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am using asp.net core 2.1 with visual studio code or rider in mac. I already have a 2.1 sdk install on mac, while using the below command

```
dotnet-ef database update --project XXXX.XXXX
```

I get an exception as

```
zsh: command not found: dotnet-ef
```

Using the command

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

getting an exception as `Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.`

Then using this command `dotnet tool restore`

```
error NU3037: Package 'dotnet-ef 3.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.

Package "dotnet-ef" failed to restore, due to Microsoft.DotNet.ToolPackage.ToolPackageException: The tool package could not be restored.
```

Answer (score 9):

For mac I need to export the below path

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, give an example of the error:

```
$ dotnet ef
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

The second and third refer to dotnet trying to find a dotnet-ef command but it cannot find it. As the third point said, dotnet-ef is not on your way.

This is what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools) says:

```
Global tools can be installed in the default directory or in a specific location. The default directory is:

OS Path

Linux/macOS $HOME/.dotnet/tools

Windows %USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools
```

So, you should add $HOME/.dotnet/tools/ to your $PATH.

For Linux and macOS, add a line to the shell configuration:

bash/ zsh:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"
```

When you start a new shell/terminal (or next time you log in) dotnet ef should work.

For Windows:

You need to add %USERPROFILE%.dotnet\tools to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I am using asp.net core 6.0
zhengguo@macdeMac-min % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

The PATH has already exist ~/.dotnet/tools
When I use dotnet aspnet-codegenerator, it works. dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator not work.